# how to use mail function in yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am a newbie in Yii Framework and creating a first yii app.
I am trying to send a mail in yii 1.1.14 but not understand how to use in yii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension called `yii mailer` which is composed of `PhpMailer`.

Here you can Download -- **[Yii-Mailer](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/)**

Copy YiiMailer folder to protected/extensions
Then Add the below code to your imports in `config/main.php`

```
'import'=>array(
        'ext.YiiMailer.YiiMailer',
        'ext.yii-mail.YiiMailMessage',
```

Then you can simply create a function in your controller to send email like this.

```
public static function SendEmail($emailContent){
    $mail = new YiiMailer();
    $mail->setFrom('info@example.com', 'Example Site Name');
    $mail->setTo('Info@example.com');
    $mail->setSubject('Example Site Name');
    $mail->setBody($emailContent);
    $mail->send();
    echo "Successfully send";
}
```

You can replace the `setTo` line with code below for getting admin email if you have specified.

```
$mail->setTo(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail']);
```

and `setBody` line with your own message or content.

```
$mail->setBody('Simple message');
```

More details can be found on how to use yii mailer [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/)